# Avoiding excessive parentheses in complex conditions

Tags: syntax

Do you consider smelly code the use of parentheses to deny the condition? If so, then what would be the correct form?

Ex:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        test += "just a test";

        if (!(array.size() == i+1)) {
            test += ",";
        }
    }
```

**the comma should not only occur in the last iteration**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the inequality operator would be better form, in this example:

```
if (array.size() != i+1) {
    test += ",";
}
```

The left side and right side are evaluated before the `!=` is performed, so if `array.size()` returns `10` and `i` is set to `5` then `array.size() != i+1` evaluates to `10 != 5+1` or `10 != 6` which return `true`. If `i` were set to `9`, then `array.size() != i+1` evaluates to `10 != 9+1` or `10 != 10` which returns `false`.

Generally the "not" operator is used when referring to a method that will return a boolean value and it is needed to test for the inverse of the condition:

```
if (!form.validated()) {
    // Do something for not validated.
}
```

Comment: In this case, it is not possible to use '! =' because it is a loop
if (array.size ()! = i + 1)

Comment: @cpll there's no space between the exclamation `!` and the equals sign `=`,  so Justin's answer should work.  Can you post more of your code?

Comment: @cpll the following is equivalent:; `!(A == B)` and `A != B`.

Comment: @cpll However, it is easier to read `A != B`, since the intent is self evident and does not require thinking about the parenthesis and extra not operator.

Comment: but it is a loop, so the value of 'i' changes with each loop

Comment: @cpll I expanded on my answer. The evaluation of the left and right sides are performed before the inequality operator is evaluated.

Comment: the comma should not only occur in the last iteration

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to C#, one edge case where this can be somewhat useful is for negating the `is` operator and pattern matching:

```
if (!(foo is Bar bar))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Outside of language specific nuances, the clearer intent would be to follow the *`not equal to`* relational operator for whatever language you're working in:

- Fortran: `/=`
- BASIC: `<>`
- Lua: `~=`
- C: `!=`
- Batch: `NEQ`

Note that some languages have special equality operators that should be used depending on the objects being compared.  In the case of Javascript, you have both Inequality (`!=`) and Non-Identity (`!==`), which behave differently.